# don't know where to put schema files in my app which is created using node.js and mongoose JS

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Where to put the schema files in my app's folders , I'm using express js with jade and mongoose,
but I don't know where to put the schema files in my app

Comment: See here http://nodetuts.com/tutorials/18-mongodb-and-mongoose.html

Answer (score 0):

I keep them under `app/models/server`  and use `app/models` for client-side models.